# How does owin/WIF verify adfs jwt token?

Tags: c#, owin, jwt, katana, adfs3.0

I have an api using *OWIN* middle ware. 
My adfs uses RSASHA256 algo for generating jwt token.

The api knows about the audience uri, federation metadata and adfs token generation URI.

I know that it uses the *public certificate* to verify the security token. But how does it get the *public certificate*? 
Does it use federation metadata? I tried *jwt.io* to verify the jwt token by using the some *x509* certificate within *fedaration metadata* but it doesn't work.

Does it talk to the *adfs* token generation URI behind the scene to get the *certificate*?

Please can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

I believe when metadata is set in your OWIN config like the following, it will perform the signature validation with the public key of cert specified in the metadata.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  WsFederationAuthenticationOptions options = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions {
    MetadataAddress = "your ADFS metadata URL",
    // Further config
  };
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(options);
```